# Softlayer "slcli vlan list" against a large account returns an error

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

My IBM Softlayer account has 255 vlans across 7 data centers, and growing. Running this command results in an error ...

```
# slcli --format json vlan list
TransportError(500): 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://api.softlayer.com/xmlrpc/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account
#
```

Seems like a bug. 255 is a suspicious number.

Excluding `--format json` makes no difference. Has anyone else experience a similar issue? If the command is chunked out by datacenter, then it works, like this ...

```
# slcli --format json vlan list -d dal06
# slcli --format json vlan list -d dal09
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the objectMask that "slcli --format json vlan list" command is using.

> mask[firewallInterfaces,hardware,networkComponents,primaryRouter[id,
>   fullyQualifiedDomainName,
>   datacenter],subnets,totalPrimaryIpAddressCount,virtualGuests]

This object mask is trying to retrieve too much information and it causes the exception that you are getting.

However it was [fixed](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/blob/master/SoftLayer/managers/network.py#L17) in the last release softlayer-python and what's currently in master branch. So, you need to use the master branch from softlayer-python.

Branch Master: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/tree/master